# Conditionally calculate values on a sheet

Tags: excel, office365

I have a sheet `allocations` dynamically capturing data:

- A widget ID
- B email of tester 1 assigned to the widget
- D widget rating by tester 1
- E email of tester 2 assigned to the widget
- G widget rating by tester 2
- I Differences in the ratings
- J Average of the ratings

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| widget_id | email1 | email1thanked | rating1 | email2 | email2thanked | rating2 | actionsent | difference | average |
| 990235 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 45 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 50 | 0 | 5 |  |
| 990236 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 55 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 53 | 0 | 2 |  |
| 990231 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 75 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990197 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 25 | 0 |  |  |
| 990003 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 65 | `iris@company.com` | 0 | 85 | 0 | 20 |  |

(columns C, F, H are email sent flags, so irrelevant for now)

In the same workbook, I also have a sheet `thresholds` which has information on the action thresholds for different levels of differences in rating:

- A what action should be taken
- B threshold of the difference in ratings to trigger this action

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| action | threshold |
| average | 5 |
| discuss | 10 |

The above values mean that I would like the ratings to be averaged if the difference between the two testers (i.e. column I in `allocations` sheet) is less than (or equal to) 5,
take a second action (irrelevant for now) if their ratings are more than 5 but less than (or equal to) 10 apart),
and take a third action (irrelevant for now) if the ratings more than 10 apart.

**What I want to happen**

If the `allocations` sheet column F value is within the `average` threshold (i.e. `thresholds` sheet cell `B2` value: 5), calculate Column J as (`AVERAGE (column D, column G)`).

Sample output:
In rows 2 and 3, column J is calculated as `=AVERAGE(D2,G2)` and  `=AVERAGE(D3,G3)` respectively.
In rows 4 and 5, column J is not calculated as in each case, column I does not have a numerical value.
In row 6, column J is not calculated as in this case the value of column I (20) is greater than the `average` threshold (5).

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| widget_id | email1 | email1thanked | rating1 | email2 | email2thanked | rating2 | actionsent | difference | average |
| 990235 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 45 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 50 | 0 | 5 | 47.5 |
| 990236 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 55 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 53 | 0 | 2 | 54 |
| 990231 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 75 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990197 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 25 | 0 |  |  |
| 990003 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 65 | `iris@company.com` | 0 | 85 | 0 | 20 |  |

**Not this**
For a variety of reasons (including the fact that I want column J to be empty if column I doesn't have a numerical value or if column J should not be calculated based on the threshold values, I do NOT want to use a simple formula like the following and copy it all the way:
`=IF(AND(I2>0,I2<=VLOOKUP(I2,thresholds!A2:B3,2)),AVERAGE(D2,G2),)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following. It is an array solution, so you don't need to expand the formula down:

```
=LET(lk, "average", thAct, A10:A11, thValue, B10:B11,
 th, XLOOKUP(lk, thAct,thValue),r_1,D2:D6, r_2, G2:G6,
 MAP(r_1,r_2, LAMBDA(x,y,
  IF(AND(ISNUMBER(x), ISNUMBER(y), y-x <= th), AVERAGE(x,y),""))))
```

or without defining the names:

```
=LET(th, XLOOKUP("average", A10:A11,B10:B11),
 MAP(D2:D6,G2:G6, LAMBDA(x,y,
  IF(AND(ISNUMBER(x), ISNUMBER(y), y-x <= th), AVERAGE(x,y),""))))
```

You can adjust the ranges to your specific problem referring to the corresponding sheets. I am not using **difference** column because it can be calculated on the fly. It only calculates the average if all conditions in `AND` call are met (both rates are numeric and the rate difference is within the threshold defined), otherwise returns an empty string. Instead of using `AND` you can multiply the conditions as follows:

```
ISNUMBER(x) * ISNUMBER(y) * (y-x <= th)
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Comment: Thanks @david-leal, this looks great. I'll test it out in a few hours as currently away from desk.

Comment: Quick question: y-x <= th checks the directional difference, right? So I should wrap y-x in ABS() ?

Comment: Yes you can wrap  in `ABS`